# SQL - How to select subelements from type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select subelements from a self-defined type in SQL.

> CREATE TYPE Name AS (
>   surname VARCHAR,
>   givenName VARCHAR );
>
> CREATE TABLE test (A Name );
>
> INSERT INTO test VALUES ( ('ter', 'minator') );

How is it possible to give me all results matching test.surname = 'ter'?

The following does not work:

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE a.surname = 'ter';

Answer (score 2):

See:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html

> For example, you might try to select some subfields from our on_hand example table with something like:
>
> ```
> SELECT item.name FROM on_hand WHERE item.price > 9.99;
> ```
>
> This will not work since the name item is taken to be a table name, not a column name of on_hand, per SQL syntax rules. You must write it like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT (item).name FROM on_hand WHERE (item).price > 9.99;
> ```
>
> or if you need to use the table name as well (for instance in a multitable query), like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT (on_hand.item).name FROM on_hand WHERE (on_hand.item).price > 9.99;
> ```